# .NET Web Service & BackgroundWorker threads

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, backgroundworker

I'm trying to do some async stuff in a webservice method. Let say I have the following API call: http://www.example.com/api.asmx

and the method is called *GetProducts()*.

I this GetProducts methods, I do some stuff (eg. get data from database) then just before i return the result, I want to do some async stuff (eg. send me an email).

So this is what I did.

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Bal blah blah.")]
public IList<Product> GetProducts()
{
    // Blah blah blah ..
    // Get data from DB .. hi DB!
    // var myData = .......
    // Moar clbuttic blahs :)  (yes, google for clbuttic if you don't know what that is)

    // Ok .. now send me an email for no particular reason, but to prove that async stuff works.
    var myObject = new MyObject();
    myObject.SendDataAsync();

    // Ok, now return the result.
    return myData;
    }
}

public class TrackingCode
{
    public void SendDataAsync()
    {
        var backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        backgroundWorker.DoWork += BackgroundWorker_DoWork;
        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * 20);
    }

    private void BackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        SendEmail();
    }
}
```

Now, when I run this code the email is never sent. If I uncomment out the Thread.Sleep .. then the email is sent.

So ... why is it that the background worker thread is torn down? is it dependant on the parent thread? Is this the wrong way I should be doing background or forked threading, in asp.net web apps?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`BackgroundWorker` is useful when you need to synchronize back to (for example) a UI* thread, eg for affinity reasons. In this case, it would seem that simply using `ThreadPool` would be more than adequate (and much simpler). If you have high volumes, then a producer/consumer queue may allow better throttling (so you don't drown in threads) - but I suspect `ThreadPool` will be fine here...

```
public void SendDataAsync()
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
    {
        SendEmail();
    });
}
```

Also - I'm not quite sure what you want to achieve by sleeping? This will just tie up a thread (not using CPU, but doing no good either). Care to elaborate? It *looks* like you are pausing your actual web page (i.e. the Sleep happens on the web-page thread, not the e-mail thread). What are you trying to do here?

*=actually, it will use whatever sync-context is in place

Comment: The sleep is commented out. I put that, there, to see if i could send an email. when the sleep is UNCOMMENTED, then the background worker thread code is executed. when the code is comented out, then the background worker thread code is never executed.

I'll try using ThreadPool instead.

Comment: > *If you have high volumes, then a producer/consumer queue may allow better throttling (so you don't drown in threads)* ooooooo!!! i'm glad u actually raised this point! the web service method is actually high volume! also, to make matters really interesting, it's not really sending an email, but actually hitting another external website (ekk, don't ask) ... so you would suggest i do this producer/consumer queue thingy? If so ... is this a good page to reference? http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx (please scroll down a fair bit to the code + an example). thoughts?

Comment: @Marc Gravell I have tried using your solution but I am just wondering why it take too much time to complete the task.

Comment: @AnandMohanAwasthi er.... what is your particular task doing? running it async doesn't make it any quicker...

Comment: @MarcGravell: For instance, let us say I need to send mail to 2000 ids with the same content. If i do this using classic way on_click event then this activity take approx 5-6 min time but if i use  ThreadPool QueueUserWorkItem delegate then it's really take long time... ( New to handle threading).. please help

Comment: @AnandMohanAwasthi you give no indication of how you are sending the mail, so ....? Most times there is no difference between a UI thread and a worker thread. If the code needs sync-context, or talks to a COM STA, then more steps will be involved. But you've given absolutely no indication of anything, so I can't even guess.

Answer (score 1):

Re producer/consumer; basically - it is just worth keeping *some* kind of throttle. At the simplest level, a `Semaphore` could be used (along with the regular `ThreadPool`) to limit things to a known amount of work (to avoid saturating the thread pool); but a producer/consumer queue would probably be more efficient and managed.

Jon Skeet has such a queue [here](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/) (`CustomThreadPool`). I could probably write some notes about it if you wanted.

That said: if you are calling off to an external web-site, it is quite likely that you will have a lot of waits on network IO / completion ports; as such, you can have a slightly higher number of threads... obviously (by contrast) if the work was CPU-bound, there is no point having more threads than you have CPU cores.

Answer (score 0):

It may torn down because after 20 seconds, that BackgroundWorker instance may be garbage collected because it has no references (gone out of scope).

Comment: Note that the Sleep() is on the web-page thread; it is more likely that the BackgroundWorker is trying to use a sync-context that is being blocked by the Sleep() itself